# lock users in SAP

Tags: settings, sap-basis

How to completely disable the lock users in SAP? What setting controls this (login / failed_user_auto_unlock)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You want to disable locked users? The ones that are already disabled? ...?

Comment: No. I want disable function "lock users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, that's not possible. You can try to set login/fails_to_user_lock to 99 and login/failed_user_auto_unlock to 1, but this will only mean that users will be licked after 99 failed attempts and unlocked again at midnight.

See http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/22/41c43ac23cef2fe10000000a114084/frameset.htm for a list of the parameters related to users and security.